# Отображение нескольких изображений как в приложении Vk для iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, gui, библиотеки

Как расставить картинки в я ячейке NSTableView таким образом: [image: Расставленные картинки в соответствии с размером]

Есть ли уже готовая библиотека/объект/что-то иное для этого, или придётся высчитывать их положение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите что больше Вам подойдет

https://github.com/Lascorbe/LAAnimatedGrid

https://github.com/AlvinNutbeij/DWGridController

https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout

https://github.com/aceisScope/WaterflowView

https://github.com/norsez/BDDynamicGridViewController

Answer (score 0):

Начиная с iOS 6 такие возможности предоставляет родной для платформы компонент UICollectionView. Аналогично для macOS версии новее 10.5 такой компонент называется NSCollectionView.